# Use of Konjunktiv 2

Tags: subjunctive

Ich habe gerade das Buch auf Deutsch gelesen (I don't know how to say in German that I was in process of reading a book, I haven't finished it yet), nämlich "Alice in Wonderland", wo ich einigen Sätzen begegnet bin, die ich nicht völlig verstehen konnte:

> Entweder mußte der Brunnen sehr tief sein, oder sie fiel sehr langsam;
>       denn sie hatte Zeit genug, sich beim Fallen umzusehen und sich zu wundern,
>       was nun wohl **geschehen würde**. Zuerst versuchte sie hinunter zu sehen, um 
>       zu wissen wohin sie **käme**, aber es war zu dunkel etwas zu erkennen.

Ich habe Fragen hinsichtlich dieser 2 Fälle von Verwendung von Konjunktiv 2. In dem ersten Falle ("würde") kann ich das mehr oder weniger verstehen, weil es hat etwas mit Unwahrscheinlichkeit zu tun. Aber warum benutzt man "käme" im letzten Satz? Das hat weder mit Unwahrscheinlichkeit, noch mit indirekter Rede etwas zu tun...

Comment: Zu deiner Frage in Klammern auf Englisch. Die motiverte diese Frage https://german.stackexchange.com/q/55199/1691

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **(I)** (...) sie hatte Zeit genug, sich beim Fallen umzusehen und sich zu wundern, was nun wohl geschehen würde (...)

Das ist ein Fall der **erlebten Rede** (des erlebten Denkens). Der Erzähler berichtet aus der Gedankenwelt einer Figur, so wie *diese* sie erlebt. Konkret wird im Beispiel aus einem präteritalen Grunderzähltempus heraus ein aus der Sicht der Erlebenden zukunftsbezogener Gedanke wiedergegeben (und zwar: *Was wird nun wohl geschehen?*). Die bevorzugte Realisierung hiervon ist im Fall von finiten Äußerungen im Deutschen die *würde*-Form. Behielte man die Frageform bei, könnte man das "Originaltempus" (aus dem Figuren-Jetzt) alternativ auch unverändert beibehalten: *Sie hatte Zeit genug, sich beim Fallen umzusehen und sich zu wundern: Was wird/würde nun wohl geschehen?*

Weitere Beispiele zur erlebten Rede findet man bei [Grammis](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/483). Wenn Sie noch nie davon gehört haben, bieten vielleicht die [Erläuterungen bei wortwuchs.net](https://wortwuchs.net/erlebte-rede/) einen Einstieg (ich habe sie selbst allerdings nur überflogen).

<sup>Anmerkung: Nach moderner Ansicht bezeichnet man die *würde*-Form in der erlebten Rede übrigens *nicht* als konjunktivisch. Das nur als Hinweis, weil in der Frage von "2 Fälle[n] von Verwendung von Konjunktiv 2" die Rede ist.</sup>

> **(II)** Zuerst versuchte sie hinunter zu sehen, um zu wissen wohin sie käme (...)

Ich muss gestehen, dass ich mich mit dem Satz etwas schwertue. Ich verstehe ihn so, dass die Figur versucht, hinunterzusehen, um *herauszufinden*, "wohin sie käme". In dem Fall erscheint mir *wissen* aber eigentlich als eher unpassende Vokabel (siehe analog: *She looked down to learn/find out/?know ...*).

Wenn die Aussage so gemeint ist wie ich sie verstehe, halte ich persönlich die Form *käme* für recht ungewöhnlich.(*) Vermutlich muss man auch diesen Fall im Kontext der erlebten Rede sehen. Eine kurze Literaturrecherche ergibt, dass dort wohl hin und wieder ein Konjunktiv II statt einer *würde*-Form auftritt, um zukunftsbezogene Gedanken auszudrücken.(**) Beispiele sind (in beiden Fällen im Rahmen eines so genannten inneren Monologs):

- *Ich **könnte** später weinen, nach Feierabend, wenn mir noch danach zumute war.* (Böll, Ansichten eines Clowns, zitiert nach Jäger 1978: 386)
- *Ich ging schon beinah in die fünfte Klasse des Gymnasiums (...) Nicht mehr lange, und ich **bekäme** einen Schülerausweis mit dem begehrten roten Stempel "über 16", der mich berechtigte, in nicht jugendfreie Filme zu gehen.* (Süskind, Die Geschichte von Herrn Sommer, zitiert nach Fabricius-Hansen et al. 2018: 170)

Als Sprecher bin ich von diesen Bildungen, ehrlich gesagt, nicht so recht überzeugt; ich selbst würde hier sicherlich keinen Konjunktiv II verwenden. Aber damit könnte die Form in der Übersetzung erklärt werden. Die Figur wollte wissen: *Wohin **werde** ich **kommen**?* Diese Zukünftigkeit wird in der erlebten Rede dann - ungewöhnlicherweise - als Konjunktiv II *(wohin sie **käme**)* umgesetzt.

---

<sup>(*) Die Figur ist ja schon im Brunnen und befindet sich im Fall. Ein kontrafaktischer Kontext (im Sinne von: *... um herauszufinden, wohin sie käme [, wenn sie spränge/...] ...*), der einen Konjunktiv II erklären könnte, fehlt somit.
(**) Fabricius-Hansen et al. (2018: 170): "Interessanterweise kommen jedoch auch eindeutige synthetische Konjunktivformen des Präteritums in erlebter Rede als Ausdruck für die figurale Zukunft vor (...)" Jäger (1978: 181), der die *würde*-Formen in der erlebten Rede auch für Konjunktive hält, bemerkt: "Bei Zukunftsbezug [können] auch die entsprechenden Konjunktivformen eintreten. Diese können (und sind das auch meist) entsprechende würde-Formen sein (...)"</sup>

<sup>Literatur: Jäger (1978), Der Konjunktiv in der deutschen Sprache der Gegenwart, Max Hueber; Fabricius-Hansen/Solfjeld/Pitz (2018), Der Konjunktiv, Stauffenburg.</sup>

Comment: Bist du sicher, dass es sich nicht um den Fall von "future in the past" mit "würde" handelt?

Comment: @Dan Im ersten Satz? Ich beschreibe doch einen Fall von _future in the past_. _Future in the past_ ist - auch im Englischen - regelmäßig ein Hinweis auf erlebtes Denken (free indirect discourse). Denkbar sind auch nicht-subjektive Perspektiven (wie in _sollte_-Konstruktionen), aber letztlich kann die Detailanalyse hier vermutlich unterbleiben, denn m.E. spricht jedenfalls das _wohl_ für erlebtes Denken. Der Erzähler scheint in der Passage ja bestens über das Geschehen Bescheid zu wissen. Er weiß, was passieren wird. Das legt eine Unsicherheitsbekundung aus Figuren-Perspektive nahe.