# Slawische Aspekte: Perfektiv (dok. сов.,...) und Imperfektiv (niedok, несов.,...)

Tags: translation, verb

Im slawischen Sprachraum unterscheidet man zwei Verbaspekte: Perfektiv und Imperfektiv. Sie entsprechen einer vollendeten und unvollendeten Version derselben Tätigkeit:

**Perfektiv**

> Ich habe einen neuen Roman gelesen (bis zur letzten Seite).
>   Przeczytałem nową powieść.
>   Я прочитал новый роман.

**Imperfektiv**

> Ich habe einen neuen Roman gelesen (der war wohl langweilig, und ich habe aufgehört).
>   Я читал новый роман.
>   Czytałam nową powieść.

Wie kann man möglichst systematisch diese Aspekte ins Deutsche übersetzten? Was ich mir soweit denken könnte, hängt vom Verb ab.

---

Wer Bulgarisch, Ukrainisch usw. spricht, der kann seine Sprache dem Beispiel oben hinzufügen (diese Sprachen habe ich leider nicht gelernt).

Comment: wie ist es mit _fertig-_, _durch-_, _aus_, _bis zum Ende_? Nicht dass ich wusste, im Gegenteil, für mich (lv->de) ist es auch manchmal ein Problem.

Comment: прочитал (perfekt) versus читал (imperfekt) zeigt die Vorsilbe "pro-" im Perfekt, das Polnische Bsp. ebenso. Man kann mal festhalten dass Deutsch jede Menge Vorsilben bietet. So beschreibt *ver-* oft, doch nicht hinreichend, die Ver-Vollständigung eines Vorgangs. *verlesen* bedeutet aber etwas anderes. *gelesen* (perfektiv) wird ggf. durch weitere Preverbalia kontextualisiert, also "in dem Buch gelesen", "angelesen" (vgl Anfang); im gegensatz dazu wäre *fertig-gelesen* (< *per-*), *aus-gelesen* oder *durch-gelesen*, mit jeweils subtil anderer Bedeutung.

Comment: @vectory Stimmt für das Beispiel, jedoch gibt es Verbpaare (Perfek-Imperfekt), deren Perfekt und Imperfekt sich nicht in Präfixen unterscheiden.

Comment: Zudem Thema fällt mir wieder mal was halbwegs passendes vom letzten Lexiconvalley Podcast ein. Im Georgischen bsw gibt es Wörter, die aus 9 Morphemen bestehen, aber äußerst kurz sind. Ähnlich sieht's mir bei *sednah* vs *sjadoh* aus. \*s(w)e- "self" + \*deH- "set, place, do" + \*Hen "in" oder "on", plus ein irgendwie gebeugtes Pronominal-Suffix; wiktionary wird einfach \*sed "sit" angeben, wie langweilig. Das pass doch nicht zu *s-* + *ja* "ego" ... was bedeuten mag, dass ich irre

Answer (score 3):

Was in slavischen Sprachen vorzugsweise durch den Verbalaspekt mit seinen grammatikalisierten Formen ausgedrückt wird - Abgeschlossenheit oder Nichtabgeschlossenheit einer Handlung - wird im Deutschen oft auf lexikalischem Wege ausgedrückt.

> BG: Свалих я.
>
> DE: Ich hab' sie rumgekriegt.

Gemeint ist (und verstanden wird) hier: Das "Rumkriegen" (ich bitte um Verzeihung wegen der sexismusverdächtigen Ausdrucksweise; es ist dem Beispiel geschuldet) fand einmal statt; oder es kann auch mehrmals stattgefunden haben, aber das ist nicht der Gesichtspunkt (Aspekt!), auf den es dem Sprecher ankommt. Er will vielmehr auf das Resultat hinweisen: Dass er die Angebetete am Ende tatsächlich gekriegt hat.

> BG: Свалях я.
>
> DE: Über einen längeren Zeitraum bin ich mit ihr ausgegangen (mit dem Ziel, sie rumzukriegen).

In diesem Fall ist die Erzählsituation auch eine andere: Der Sprecher ist vermutlich dabei, eine längere Geschichte zu erzählen, und in deren Verlauf werden auch die Flirt- und Dating-Aktivitäten dargestellt, aber eben mit Blick auf deren Verlauf, nicht so sehr das Ergebnis. In der Tat ist es sowohl im deutschen wie im bulgarischen Beispiel nicht klar, ob dem Protagonisten das "Rumkriegen" am Ende gelungen ist.

Wie man an den Beispielen sieht, liegt es im Deutschen nahe, den Aspekt (den Blick auf die Handlung bzw. das Resultat) durch eine spezielle Wortwahl auszudrücken. Die Wortwahl  ist nun nicht so leicht regelhaft vorhersehbar, sondern hängt stark vom Kontext ab.

Allerdings gibt es im Deutschen auch die Unterscheidung von Perfekt und Präteritum als Tempus, was ja im Grunde eine ähnliche Unterscheidung trägt:

> BG: Седнах при тях.
>
> DE: Ich habe mich zu ihnen gesetzt.

Hier wird auf das Resultat abgehoben: Es geht dem Sprecher hier nicht um den Vorgang des zum Tisch Gehens und sich dann Niederlassens (prozedural) sondern um das Resultat: dass er dann mit diesen und jenen Leuten zusammensaß.

> BG: Сядох.
>
> DE: Ich setzte mich / Ich setzte mich hin.

Bei *Ich setzte mich* ist wie im Bulgarischen durch die Tempusform ausgedrückt, dass der Sprecher dabei vor allem den Vorgang an sich meint und nicht das Resultat. So etwas sagt man häufig als Teil einer Erzählung, wenn die Teilhandlung also eingebettet ist in eine längere Kette konsekutiver Handlungen.

Zum "Aspekt" in den slavischen Sprachen - sowie zu Ausdrucksformen, die diese Funktion in anderen Sprachfamilien übernehmen - gibt es umfangreiche Forschungliteratur. Eine Autorin, die sich viel mit diesen Fragen befasst hat, ist die bayerisch-schweizerische Slavistin Barbara Sonnenhauser. Bei ihr findet man auch Arbeiten zu vergleichbaren Ausdrucksformen im Bairischen.

---

PS: Das bulgarische Beispiel eignet sich übrigens für eine hübsche kontrastive Verdichtung:

> BG: Свалях я но не я свалих.
>
> DE: Ich hab' sie intensiv angebaggert, aber ich hab' sie am Ende dann leider doch nicht rumgekriegt.

Man sieht hier auch, wie im Deutschen der Aspekt lexikalisch ausgedrückt wird mit Wörtchen und Ausdrücken wie "am Ende", "dann", "doch", "intensiv", etc.

Die Möglichkeit der Unterscheidung durch die Tempus-Arten Perfekt und Prästeritum wird im diesem (alltagssprachlichen) Beispiel nicht genutzt. Diese Unterscheidung findet sich eher in elaborierteren schriftsprachlichen Texten. In der legeren Alltagssprache tendiert man im Deutschen dazu, die "habe"-Vergangenheit zu nutzen und Verbalaspekt durch Zusatzwörtchen einzuflechten.

Comment: "Свалях я но не я свалих." -- jeh mich be-müht, ich, noch nicht mich ge-mocht; das B=V irritiert etwas, dachte erst an "Balz", aber da ist wohl eher "Wille", oder "Folge" im Spiel"? Ich habe Sie verfolgt, doch ohne Erfolg. Haha, ich mach nur Spaß, habe das Wörterbuch grad verlegt. Wollte nur sagen, deine Übersetzung ist doch absichtlich besonders lang, wohl mit der Absicht, nicht unangemessen viel Zeit darauf zu verwenden.

Comment: "Allerdings gibt es im Deutschen auch die Unterscheidung von Perfekt und Präteritum als Tempus" - diese Unterscheidung scheint aber im Deutschen zumindest regionsabhängig weitestgehend verschwunden zu sein. Als Süddeutscher nehme ich "Ich setzte mich zu ihnen." als gehobener/schriftsprachlicher wahr als "Ich habe mich zu ihnen gesetzt.", einen (auch nur angedeuteten) inhaltlichen Unterschied kann ich beim besten Willen nicht erkennen.

Comment: @vectory  Ja, meine Übersetzung ist absichtlich lang. Ich möchte aber behaupten, dass die deutsche Formulierung, die ich geliefert habe, nicht unrealistisch ist: Der Satz könnte genau so, Wort für Wort, in einem lockeren Gespräch zwischen Freunden vorkommen.

Answer (score 2):

Es gibt keine einheitliche allgemeine Regel, weil es kein solches Konzept im Deutschen gibt. Daher werden die Übersetzungen immer vom Kontext abhändig.  Ansonsten kann ich zu russischen Lehrbüchern zum Thema raten.

Man könnte das z.B. mal mit "mal" versuchen, mit Vorsilben die quasi perfektiv sind, wie "zer-" usw.

Comment: Einwand: Das "Konzept" gibt es im Deutschen durchaus. "Konzept" meint ja eine Denkform, Denkfigur, Betrachtungsweise. Was es im Deutschen nicht so ausgeprägt wie im Slawischen gibt, ist die Umsetzung dieses Konzepts in eine grammatikalisierte (hier sogar: morphologisierte) Form.